# How can you profile a .Net Core Azure Function in consumption mode?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, profiler

I would like to profile a .Net Core Azure Function such that I can see a breakdown of how long each method invocation takes within the call stack. I believe that Application Insights does not provide such detail.

I have searched for different profilers on the web and it appears that none have support for Azure Functions in consumption mode. Stackify has released Retrace with support for Azure Functions in App Service Plan mode only (https://stackify.com/announcing-retrace-azure-functions-preview/). I have tried to use JetBrain's dotTrace to run my Function App exe file to no success.

Are there any profilers that can be used to profile .Net Core Azure Functions in consumption mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we do not have a profiler for function apps. You could try to use the output of the logs and do some post processing to figure each method invocations in your function app.

If you want to make a feature request for Azure Functions you can leave that feedback here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions

Comment: I've created a feature request for an Azure Function Profiler: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/37708147-profiler-support-for-net-core-azure-functions . Anybody reading this that wants a profiler, please add your vote to the request.